# SPARQL query in Jena Syntax

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web

I have this SPARQL query which works fine inside Protege SPARQL tab but it does not work inside Jena code. 
Kindly if some one provide it in correct Jena syntax as I have never used nested SELECT clause in Jena code.

```sql
SELECT ?student ?topScore WHERE {
   {
    SELECT (MAX(?score) AS ?topScore) WHERE {
         ?student dd:EnglishPercentage ?score .
    }
   }
    ?student dd:EnglishPercentage  ?topScore .
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" means what? Exception? If yes, show the whole error stack trace. Empty result? If yes, this is not a minimal example. Show data + code. Prefix declaration in the query is missing, this could for instance lead t a parse exception.

Comment: By the way, which Jena version do you use? This query needs SPARQL 1.1, so Jena 2.10 or even better 3.x is recommended.

Comment: The query is perfectly fine SPARQL 1.1 *if* a prefix is added (as required by the standard).

Comment: String queryString2= 
                   "prefix dd:<http://www.semanticweb.org/t/ontologies/2016/7/myOWL#>"+
         "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "  +
                   
          "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
                     "SELECT  ?student ?highScore " +
          " WHERE {" + " {"+ "select  (max(?score) as ?highScore)" + " { ?student dd:Englishscore ?score" + 
" }" +
"  } " +Englishscore ?highScore"   +     
         "}";

Comment: No no no, edit your question please. And don't post Java String concatenation code. that's even more weird to read.

Comment: According to your comment, the query that you build is wrong resp. it will **not** compile. The same thing that we told you several times on the Jena mailing list, check the query that you build by printing it to the console. And according to the exception that you get - there is no data that matches the query - which might happen because of your query build by Java Strings concatenated.

Comment: Javed, according to the discussion on the Jena mailing list, you solved the problem. Please post the answer here such that the topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole query. I am using 3.x version of Jena

```
String queryString2 = 
                   "prefix dd:<http://www.semanticweb.org/t/ontologies/2016/7/myOWL#>"+
         "PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "  +

          "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
                     "SELECT  ?student ?highScore " +
          " WHERE {" + " {"+ "select  (max(?score) as ?highScore)" + " { ?student dd:Englishscore ?score" + 
" }" +
"  } " +Englishscore ?highScore"   +     
         "}";    
Query query2 = QueryFactory.create(queryString2);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query2, model) ;
ResultSet results2 = qexec.execSelect() ;

Literal r= results2.next().get("highScore").asLiteral();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,r.toString());
```

Comment: And exception is:: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: QueryIteratorCloseable

Comment: @JavedKhan The query that you build is wrong resp. it will not compile. -> missing quotes before the last occurrence of EnglishScore and missing prefix. Javad, the same thing that we told you several times on the Jena mailing list, check the query that you build by printing it to the console. And according to the exception that you get - there is no data that matches the query - which might happen because of your wrong query